# Notation for formal language

Tags: notation, formal-languages

Let $\Sigma = \{\alpha, \beta \}$ and $L = \{\alpha (\beta \alpha)^*\}$

I don't understand the notation for the language $L$. Does it mean that every string must start with $\alpha$, and then have an arbitrary number of ($\beta\alpha$) after it?

Comment: The notation is incorrect. It should be $L = \alpha (\beta \alpha)^*$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly right.  And the 'arbitrary number' is 0 or more. So, just having $\alpha$ would be a word in this language.

Comment: Is there a different notation to show that any order can be used? Such as $\beta$ beginning before $\alpha$